# Wordpress bedrock framework with read and write databases

Tags: database, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

we are using bedrock framework for a WP site and now we are planning to add multiple databases(read/write databases). We are using AWS RDS aurora for database. We found below 2 options but we were unable to find proper documentation for this to implement on a bedrock framework.
HyperDB: https://wordpress.org/plugins/hyperdb/
LudicrousDB: https://github.com/stuttter/ludicrousdb

Any kind help is greatly appreciated

Comment: What exactly is your problem? From your question it's unclear where your problem is. You can connect to anything through WordPress if you develop the code and place it in your theme files or a plugin.

Comment: Hi flomei, my problem is i that am not sure where exactly should i place the below files:

db.php <-> wp-content/db.php - Bootstrap for replacement $wpdb object

db-error.php <-> wp-content/db-error.php - Endpoint for fatal database error output to users

db-config.php <-> ABSPATH/db-config.php - For configuring your database environment


as the bedrock framework has a different folder structure. Thanks for the reply

Comment: You should probably have a look at this: [Organizing Theme Files](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/) Everything theme-related should live inside the `/wp-content/themes/your-theme/` folder. There you can rebuild the framework structure if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about HyperDB, but for LudicrousDB you can put db.php and db-error.php in web/app.

db-config.php can be placed in web/.

ludicrousdb looks in ABSPATH, then in WP_CONTENT_DIR, and finally 1 folder above ABSPATH.

You can see it here in the first function:
https://github.com/stuttter/ludicrousdb/blob/master/ludicrousdb/includes/functions.php